# Flutter : When i want to display a image from firebase storage it is not working

Tags: flutter, firebase, http-status-code-404, firebase-storage

This is what it getting in the terminal.

```
E/StorageException( 1371): StorageException has occurred.
E/StorageException( 1371): Object does not exist at location.
E/StorageException( 1371):  Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
E/StorageException( 1371): {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found."  }}
E/StorageException( 1371): java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found."  }}
E/StorageException( 1371):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(NetworkRequest.java:445)
E/StorageException( 1371):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(NetworkRequest.java:462)
E/StorageException( 1371):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(NetworkRequest.java:453)
E/StorageException( 1371):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:272)
E/StorageException( 1371):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:289)
E/StorageException( 1371):  at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:76)
E/StorageException( 1371):  at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:68)
E/StorageException( 1371):  at com.google.firebase.storage.GetDownloadUrlTask.run(GetDownloadUrlTask.java:77)
E/StorageException( 1371):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/StorageException( 1371):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/StorageException( 1371):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
I/flutter ( 1371): [firebase_storage/object-not-found] No object exists at the desired reference.
```

**My Code to display the image:- **

```
FutureBuilder(
          future: getUserImagePath(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
                snapshot.hasData) {
              return Image.network(
                snapshot.data!,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              );
            }
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              print(snapshot.error);
            }
            return Container();
          }),



  Future<String> getUserImagePath() async {
    final user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    String userEmail = user!.email.toString();
    print(userEmail);
    final userRef = await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();
    String urlPath = 'users/${userEmail}/userProfile.jpeg';
    final userProfileUrl = await userRef.child(urlPath).getDownloadURL();
    print(userProfileUrl);

    return userProfileUrl;
  }
```

[image]

Comment: The path of the image your code is requesting does not match the path of the file in storage.  Your code asks for "jpeg" but your filename is "jpg".  That's why the error is saying the file does not exist.

Comment: In addition to the filename extension: the path in your code ends with `userProfile.jpeg`, but in the screenshot it's `UserProfile.jpg` with an uppercase U. Casing matters, so the two need to be exactly the same.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Correct the file name with extension both in code and storage. Please check the storage security rule for reading permission.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).